# A convex subset of a set has 'smaller' boundary than the set?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Let $A\subseteq B$ be subsets of the real plane. Show that if $A$ is convex and $B$ is bounded, then the length of the border of $A$  $\leq$ the length of the border of $B$.

Comment: Maybe a bit too late for a comment.... Why the border of $A$ should have length?  Is this border always a rectifiable curve?

Answer (score 8):

1. Given any convex closed subset $A$ of a Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$, we can define the *nearest-point projection* $p_A\colon\mathbb R^n\to A$ by sending each point $x\in\mathbb R^n$ into $y\in A$ that attains the minimum $\min_{y\in A}|x-y|$. Due to the convexity of $A$, $p_A$ is well-defined. This concept generalizes the orthogonal projection onto a linear subspace.
2. A notable property of orthogonal projections is shared by $p_A$: it is a *contraction* in the sense that $|p_A(x)-p_A(y)|\le |x-y|$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$.
3. It remains to show that $p_A$ maps $\partial B$ onto $\partial A$. The claim then follows from the fact that contractions do not increase length (or area, etc).

The proofs of 2 and 3 are easier to carry out yourself than to watch/read someone else do it.

Answer (score 3):

First, show that for a general half-space $H$, $B\cap H$ has smaller boundary than $B$.

If $A$ is sufficiently smooth, you can write $A$ as the intersection of $B$ with a countable family of half-spaces, say

$$A=B\cap(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty H_k).$$

From this (and lower semicontinuity of the perimeter functional, see any text of sets of finite perimeter), it follows that $A$ has smaller boundary than $B$.

Comment: @Martjin. I know an elementary argument to show that the perimeter of a convex poligon 'inside' a simple closed curve is smaller than the length of the curve. I think this argument could be passed to the limit to show it for an arbitrary convex curve.

Comment: In any case I think that an analogous statement is true in any dimension.

Comment: @Sgernesto: probably, this is the same argument