# Is the contour of a figure A inside another figure B, smaller than the contour of B?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, geometry, riemannian-geometry, analytic-geometry

I came up with this question after playing around with some simple geometric arguments:

Let's say that a **convex figure** is any convex set of points of $\mathbb{R}^2$, with topological boundary any simple closed arc.

Suppose we have two convex figures $A$ and $B$, such that $B\subset A$.

[image]
If $L_A, L_B$ are the lengths of their respective boundaries then **I have the feeling** that  $L_A \ge L_B$. Is this true or do I have an mal illusion here? I have tried to prove it by the Green's theorem but convexivity is out of hand here. Thanks for any advise.

**EDIT**

After this usefull link [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262568/a-convex-subset-of-a-set-has-smaller-boundary-than-the-set) of @Eevee Trainer, I realised that nearest-point projection map $p_A$ is the key to prove that $L_A \ge L_B$. But I still have some concerns:

1. Does any simple closed arc $C$ have **length** $L_C=\sup \{\text{length of any polygon}\quad X_1 X_2\ldots X_n, \text{ for any division } X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n \text{ of the arc } C \}$ ?
2. In order to prove that $p_A$ is onto arc $B$, we need to assume further that the points of $B$ that can have a tangent line is dense on the arc. In that case the rectilinear to the point $y$ meets arc $A$ to a point $x$, and then $p_A(x)=y$. So is it true for a simple closed arc?

Thanks again for any feedback.

Comment: Possibly useful -- [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262568/a-convex-subset-of-a-set-has-smaller-boundary-than-the-set)

Comment: $L_B$ could be constructed

Comment: @Moti,  sorry what do you mean by "could be constructed"?

Comment: of any length almost...

Comment: Was interrupted while writing it.

Comment: @Moti I do not think this is true for convex curves

Comment: You are right - I missed the CONVEX.